# TypeError: Cadastro.findALL is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to show all the information from the table "cadastros" (in database "Cadastro") in the view "level", but the "TypeError: Cadastro.findALL is not a function" appears all the time.
Could you help me?
This is my code:

routes/admin.js :

```
const router = express.Router()
const Cadastro = require('../moldels/Cadastro')

router.get('/level', function(req,res){
    Cadastro.findALL().then(function(cadastros){            
    res.render('./views/admin/level', {cadastros: cadastros})
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

moldels/Cadastro.js:

```
const db = require('../routes/db')

const Cadastro = db.sequelize.define('cadastros', {
    nome: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    sobrenome: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    nomeUsuario: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    senha: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

module.exports = Cadastro
```

views/admin/level:

```
<h2> Lista:</h2>
{{#each cadastros}}
<div class= "card">
    <div class= "card-body">
        <h4>{{nome}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What is in `'../routes/db'`? It's hard to help without knowing what that `db` you're requiring is.

Comment: db is where I connect with database

Comment: like the code: 

const sequelize = new Sequelize('table', 'user', 'password', {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

module.exports = {
Sequelize: Sequelize,
sequelize: sequelize
}